# undefined method 'login' for {}:Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash

Hi I am new to ruby on rails. I am developing small application. When I tries to login to my application it gives me error **ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `login' for {}:Hash):**

my form for sign in looks like

```
<%= form_for("user", :url => user_session_path, :html => { :id => "signinForm", :class => "regForms round", :style => "padding:0px 20px 20px;" }) do |f| %>
            <div class="signinupformDiv">
                <%= f.text_field :login, :class => "signupin-field-uname signupin-field last", :placeholder => "" %> // error occurred for this line as undefined method log in
                <%= f.label :login, :class => "signupin-label" %>
            </div>
            <div class="signinupformDiv">
                <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "signupin-field-pwd signupin-field last", :placeholder => "" %> //Error occurred at this line as undefined method password..    
                <%= f.label :password, :class => "signupin-label" %>
            </div>
            <div class="signupin-bl" style="width:240px;margin:0px auto 10px;"><span id="signinbutton-span" style="min-width:81px;text-align:center; margin-right:20px;"><%= f.submit 'Sign In', :id => "signInButton", :class => "regFormButton" %></span><%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path('user') %></div>
<% end %>
```

is there any way to handle this error. Whether I am doing some thing wrong?

Need Help... Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller for `@user`. It should be setting the correct value, it seems like it's set to an empty hash (`{}`) that's why you're getting that error.

I don't know how you have it set up but you can probably do something like this instead:

```
@user = User.new
```